# Standalone convert does not produce png, while the command "convert <INFILE> <OUTFILE>" works well

Tags: standalone, convert

I use the `standalone` package to produce png from pdf. It functioned well before, but today the bulid process end up with a warning and no png is exported:

```
Conversion unsuccessful!
(standalone)    There might be something wrong with your
(standalone)    conversation software or the file permissions!
```

The MWE:

```latex
% main.tex
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}

\begin{document}
aaa
\end{document}
```

Run "convert main.pdf main.png" causes a warning:
``` convert: profile 'icc': 'RGB ': RGB color space not permitted on grayscale PNG ``main.png' @ warning/png.c/MagickPNGWarningHandler/1526. ```,
**but main.png is produced anyway!**

I try to export a colored picture, but it is not exported by `standalone` as well:

```latex
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\usepackage[]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\color{blue} aaa
\end{document}
```

I use Visual Studio Code + Latex-workshop for latex editing. Here is my environment information:

VSCode：

Version: 1.75.1 (system setup)

Commit: 441438abd1ac652551dbe4d408dfcec8a499b8bf

Date: 2023-02-08T21:32:34.589Z

Electron: 19.1.9

Chromium: 102.0.5005.194

Node.js: 16.14.2

V8: 10.2.154.23-electron.0

OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19044

Sandboxed: No

LaTeX Workshop:
Version: v9.6.0

Comment: I do not have Windows now, but the `convert` shell command has a Windows meaning that differs from the ImageMagick `convert`. The command `im convert` was introduced to avoid conflict. But `standalone` docs 5.6.2, implies that it is looking for `imgconvert`. Really? Also, `standalone` uses shell escape. Is it enabled in your build? Is there a permission conflict (different for TeX/ImageMagick?). Those are some things to look at. If png is produced, is it really grayscale (single channel gray) or is it RGB gray (three channels), and does it have an embedded *.icc color profile (it should not).

Comment: Correction: `magick convert` not `im convert`. With Graphics Magick, the command is `gm convert`.

Comment: @rallg I work out by adding a `latexmkrc` file with system cmd call. It seems caused by the dump files produced by latexmk.

Comment: Same problem with OS X ventura: in a shell `convert -density 300 file.pdf file.png` works well but with the same warning. No result with lualatex compilation and standalone